# What does "$S\times S\rightarrow R$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

In the textbook, Mathematical Methods and Algorighms for Signal Processing, Tood K. Moon, the $\mathbf{inner\;product}$ is defined it is a function $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:S\times S\rightarrow R$ when $S$ is a vector space defined over a scalar field $R$.
What does $S\times S\rightarrow R$ mean? I just know that inner product means like $x^Ty$ making some  It is not intuitive to understand for me.
Thank you.

Comment: It simply means that it is an operator which takes two vectors from the Vector space $S$ (as inputs) and it gives back a value in a scalar field $R$ (as output).

Comment: The *use* of inner products is that they provide a means of defining angles and lengths of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the inner product is simply a binary operation. Given any two elements of $S$ as input, the inner product will somehow convert the ordered pair into a new element that belongs in $R$ as output.

For example, take $S = \mathbb R^2$ and $R = \mathbb R$. Then using the dot product as our inner product, we have for example that:
$$
\left\langle
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 3
\end{bmatrix}}_{\in ~ \mathbb R^2}
,
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix}}_{\in ~ \mathbb R^2}
\right\rangle
= \underbrace{10}_{\in ~ \mathbb R}
$$

Comment: I've understood the principle but why does it use the notation $\times$? It does not seem to clearly times.

Comment: It's not quite a time operation, but a Cartesian product. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 0):

The inner product that you know is an example of an inner product. It is a function which assigns a pair $(v,w)$ to an element in $R$, satisfying some axioms. The notation $S \times S \to R$ means in this case, that this is a function from the cartesian product (which consists of elements $(v,w) \in S \times S$ to the field $R$. But instead of writing $f: S \times S \to R$ and $f(v,w)$ we want to write $\langle v, w \rangle$.